# What is the reason to do up casting in java?

Tags: java

If Animal is Parent and dog is its child through inheritance please tell me difference between statement no 1 and 2.

```
Animal anim = new Dog(); // 1
Dog d=new Dog(); 
Animal anim = d;         // 2
```

Comment: Did you do a little/any research before asking this question? It is way to broad and there are plenty of tutorials out there to help you out.

Comment: Because ["Code to an interface"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface) is a thing.  Note that it's not always a thing and you should only use super-classes/interfaces when it makes sense to do so.

Comment: your both statements are same, IMO

Comment: Both are the same - you may only want to keep a Dog reference around for easy access. (Whats the point in mentioning, that its  a Dog if you are only dealing with Animals )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a difference, IMO. You have a handle to a Dog new Dog object. The reason to do the second is if for some reason you need to call methods on Dog that don't exist in Animal, so you're going to do something like d.playFetch().